# javascript compress django decompress

Tags: javascript, python, django, compression

I need to send a very big string from browser to server, so I want to compress it using javascript on client side and then decompress on server using django/python.
Could you give any ideas how is better to do that?

Comment: How big is the string?

Comment: html page length ~ 100000

Comment: I honestly really doubt you'll compress it better than gzip.